# Assign ID for Road segment ( Latitude longitude) in R Code

Tags: r, data-mining, latitude-longitude, spatial

I want your ideas and suggestion in handling the following dataset:

```
 Start_Latitude    Start_Longitude   End_Latitude    End_Longitude       Date        Avg_Speed
     41.92446         -87.68654       41.93184        -87.67459     2020-06-11 6:00       40
     41.90367         -87.63233       41.91600        -87.61911     2020-06-11 6:00       35
     41.86468         -87.76746       41.82341        -87.69162     2020-06-11 6:00       54
     41.96075         -87.74756       41.76543        -87.67459     2020-06-11 6:00       45
```

I have the variables :Start_Latitude, Start_Longitude, and End_Latitude, End_Longitude that represent road segment and I have the average speed of each road segment.

I want to assign Id for each road segment that starts with Latitude and Longitude, and ends with Latitude and Longitude, so I can compare the average speed with another road segment.

The data I want will look like :

```
   St_Lat_Long             End_Lat_Long              Date         Avg_Speed     ID
41.92446, -87.6865       41.93184,-87.67459     2020-06-11 6:00       40         1
41.90367,-87.63233       41.91600,-87.61911     2020-06-11 6:00       35         2
41.86468,-87.76746       41.82341,-87.69162     2020-06-11 6:00       54         3
41.96075,-87.74756       41.76543,-87.67459     2020-06-11 6:00       45         4
```

How can I assign Id in R code?
I have the following code that assign ID for one spatial point that has Start_Latitude, Start_Longitude ( 2 coordinates:

```
Data$ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(df[1:2]))

 Latitude    Longitude          Date          Avg_Speed    ID
41.92446     -87.68654    2020-06-11 6:00       40          1
41.90367     -87.63233    2020-06-11 6:00       35          2
41.86468     -87.76746    2020-06-11 6:00       54          3
41.96075     -87.74756    2020-06-11 6:00       45          4
```

Also, is it possible  to plot all roads segment on the map using 4 coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach to addressing the first part of your post using `base`:

**Data**

```
foo <- tibble::tribble(~Start_Latitude, ~Start_Longitude, ~End_Latitude,    ~End_Longitude, ~Date,           ~Avg_Speed,
                        41.92446,       -87.68654,         41.93184,        -87.67459,      '2020-06-11 6:00',       40,
                        41.90367,       -87.63233,         41.91600,        -87.61911,      '2020-06-11 6:00',       35,
                        41.86468,       -87.76746,         41.82341,        -87.69162,      '2020-06-11 6:00',       54,
                        41.96075,       -87.74756,         41.76543,        -87.67459,      '2020-06-11 6:00',       45)
```

**Code**

```
foo$St_lat_long = paste(foo$Start_Latitude, foo$Start_Longitude, sep = ", ")
foo$End_lat_long = paste(foo$End_Latitude, foo$End_Longitude, sep = ", ")
foo2 <- foo[,c(7,8,5,6)]
foo2$ID <- seq.int(nrow(foo2))
```

**Output**

```
  St_lat_long           End_lat_long          Date            Avg_Speed    ID
  41.92446, -87.68654   41.93184, -87.67459   2020-06-11 6:00        40     1
  41.90367, -87.63233   41.916,   -87.61911   2020-06-11 6:00        35     2
  41.86468, -87.76746   41.82341, -87.69162   2020-06-11 6:00        54     3
  41.96075, -87.74756   41.76543, -87.67459   2020-06-11 6:00        45     4
```

**Mapping Data**

You provided the following data in your post:

```r
    foo <- tibble::tribble(~Latitude, ~Longitude, ~Date, ~Avg_Speed, ~ID, 
    41.92446, -87.68654, "2020-06-11 6:00", 40, 1, 41.90367, 
    -87.63233, "2020-06-11 6:00", 35, 2, 41.86468, -87.76746, 
    "2020-06-11 6:00", 54, 3, 41.96075, -87.74756, "2020-06-11 6:00", 
    45, 4)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   Latitude Longitude Date            Avg_Speed    ID
#>      <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     41.9     -87.7 2020-06-11 6:00        40     1
#> 2     41.9     -87.6 2020-06-11 6:00        35     2
#> 3     41.9     -87.8 2020-06-11 6:00        54     3
#> 4     42.0     -87.7 2020-06-11 6:00        45     4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Creating a Map with Latitude and Longitude**

Here is an approach to mapping the final part of your question using the `leaflet` package:

```r
library(leaflet) %>%
leaflet(foo) %>% 
addTiles() %>% 
addCircleMarkers(lat = ~Latitude, 
                 lng = ~Longitude, 
                 popup = paste("<b>Date:</b>", foo$Date, "<br>", 
                               "<b>Avergae Speed:</b>", foo$Avg_Speed, "<br>", 
                               "<b>ID:</b>", foo$ID, "<br>"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Output**

I published the interactive leaflet to my RPubs. [Here is a link](https://rpubs.com/flyingspoon/630823)

Comment: Is it possible to map the data with the start_Lat_Long, and the End_Lat_Long?  I tried using your code but it didn't work for mapping

Comment: Hi Reta. I am not entirely sure how to address this additional question. I have posted to Ronak's answer seeing if he could take a stab at it or at least contribute to a possible way forward.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the columns using `unite`, `paste` them and create a unique `ID` using `match` and `unique`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(St_Lat_Long, Start_Latitude, Start_Longitude, sep = ',') %>%
  unite(End_Lat_Long, End_Latitude, End_Longitude, sep = ',') %>%
  mutate(temp = paste(St_Lat_Long,End_Lat_Long), 
         ID = match(temp, unique(temp))) %>%
  select(-temp)



# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  St_Lat_Long        End_Lat_Long       Date            Avg_Speed    ID
#  <chr>              <chr>              <chr>               <dbl> <int>
#1 41.92446,-87.68654 41.93184,-87.67459 2020-06-11 6:00        40     1
#2 41.90367,-87.63233 41.916,-87.61911   2020-06-11 6:00        35     2
#3 41.86468,-87.76746 41.82341,-87.69162 2020-06-11 6:00        54     3
#4 41.96075,-87.74756 41.76543,-87.67459 2020-06-11 6:00        45     4
```

In the new `dplyr 1.0.0` you can use `cur_group_id` which assigns a unique number to every group.

```
df %>%
  unite(St_Lat_Long, Start_Latitude, Start_Longitude, sep = ',') %>%
  unite(End_Lat_Long, End_Latitude, End_Longitude, sep = ',') %>%
  group_by(St_Lat_Long, End_Lat_Long) %>%
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id())
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, Reta asked an additional question on my answer. I am not savvy enough to answer it... perhaps you could take a stab at it?

Comment: I am not sure what they mean by mapping here.

Answer (score 0):

A way using `dplyr` and `stringr`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(St_Lat_Long = str_c(Start_Latitude, ", ", Start_Longitude),
         End_Lat_Long = str_c(End_Latitude, ", ", End_Longitude)) %>%
  select(St_Lat_Long, End_Lat_Long, Date, Avg_Speed) %>%
  distinct(across(ends_with("Lat_Long")), .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number())
```

yields

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  St_Lat_Long         End_Lat_Long        Date            Avg_Speed    ID
  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>               <dbl> <int>
1 41.92446, -87.68654 41.93184, -87.67459 2020-06-11 6:00        40     1
2 41.90367, -87.63233 41.916, -87.61911   2020-06-11 6:00        35     2
3 41.86468, -87.76746 41.82341, -87.69162 2020-06-11 6:00        54     3
4 41.96075, -87.74756 41.76543, -87.67459 2020-06-11 6:00        45     4
```